# How to differentiate between selected pictures in VBA code excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a total beginner in VBA coding. I try to arrange 3 pictures in Excel as follows:

1. Bring all selected pictures to the same size.
2. Bring the 3 selected pictures 188 point away from each other in 1 row.

My problem is that I have no idea how to differentiate beween the pictures. With my code the pictures overlap. Thats my code:

```
Sub ArrangePics()

' ArrangePics Macro

    Dim objPic As Object

    For Each objPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        With objPic.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.1)
            .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.1)
        End With
    Next

    Selection.ShapeRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, msoFalse


Dim intX As Integer
intX = 1
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To 2 Step 1

   Selection.ShapeRange.Left = intX * 188

Next


'       Selection.Cut

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the name or index? This might help https://exceloffthegrid.com/vba-code-to-insert-move-delete-and-control-pictures/

Comment: Consider this as your lower loop ...

Dim intX As Integer
intX = 1
For Each objPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        With objPic.ShapeRange
              .ShapeRange.Left = intX
              intX = .ShapeRange.Width + .ShapeRange.Left + 188
Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could e after this:

```
Dim xPic As Long

Dim objPic As Object
For Each objPic In Selection
    If TypeOf objPic Is Picture Then ' be sure to deal with pics only
        With objPic.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.1)
            .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(5.1)

            .Top = 200 ' same row for all pictures
            .Left = xPic
            xPic = xPic + 188 ' update xPic
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: you are welcome. you may want to mark the answer as accepted to direct future readers, too...